# Как записать в базу данных выбранные в select значения?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма записи. Я организую вывод ФИО в `select` с помощью этого кода:.

```
<?php
include("../bd.php");
connect();


// вывод фио доктора
$sotr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM doctor");
if ($sotr == true) {
     echo "<select>";
     while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($sotr)) {
          echo "<option>".$s['family']." ".$s['name']." ".$s['patronymic']."</option>";
     }
    echo "</select>";
}
else {
    echo "Сотрудники отсутствуют";
}
```

Как записать в базу данных выбранные в `select` значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это

```
echo "<select>";
```

заменить на

```
echo "<form action='post_data.php' method='get'><select id='doctorName' name='doctorName'>";
```

это

```
echo "</select>";
```

заменить на

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'></select></form>";
```

добавить файл post_data.php с содержимым

```
<?php
include("../bd.php");
connect();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO doctor_result (name) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['doctorName']) . "')");
?>
```

где doctor_result - созданная вами таблица и имеющая поле "name"

Comment: а как сделать если у меня есть уже формочка готовая?посмотри

Comment: яж написал выше конкретно для твоей формочки.....но результат куда вставлять яж не знаю....создай таблицу для этого...(куда ты хочешь сохранить доктора выбранного из формочки)

Comment: как добавить еще в обработчик еще данные для записи?

Comment: все спасибо..разобрался

Comment: @LesyukAlexey Вы когда ответы пишите, указывайте всегда, что лучше использовать для работы с MySQL расширения mysqli или лучше PDO. И использовать привязываемые переменные. Потому как уже появляются вопросы "ой, в моем php нет функций mysql_*, что делать".

Comment: что значит лучше?.....тому кто спрашивает лучше давать ответ в тех рамках и тех функциях которые уже фигурируют в его задаче...а в задаче фигурирует mysql_query,  нет смысла  давать и советовать то что не нужно автору..(иначе я бы в данном ответе писал бы паттерн с кодом в 10-20 раз больше и рассказывал бы автору про DOCTRINE и т.д)